# User input getting skipped

Tags: c, scanf

I want to get input for three different variables of a structure but every time one or the other user input gets skipped. I am new to programming and I don't know what is going on. Please help me to understand the problem here.
I've tried to search for a solution to this problem but couldn't figure it out myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct details
{
    char name[50];
    char license[30];
    char route[120];
    int km;
} driver1, driver2, driver3;

int main()
{
    printf("Driver 1\n");
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver1.name);
    printf("License Number: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver1.license);
    printf("Route: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver1.route);
    printf("Approx km driven: ");
    scanf("%d", &driver1.km);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Driver 2\n");
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver2.name);
    printf("License Number: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver2.license);
    printf("Route: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver2.route);
    printf("Approx km driven: ");
    scanf("%d", &driver2.km);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Driver 3\n");
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver3.name);
    printf("License Number: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver3.license);
    printf("Route: ");
    scanf("%s", &driver3.route);
    printf("Approx km driven: ");
    scanf("%d", &driver3.km);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Driver 1 details:\n");
    printf(" Name: %s\n", driver1.name);
    printf(" License number: %s\n", driver1.license);
    printf(" Route: %s\n", driver1.route);
    printf(" Apprrox km driven: %d", driver1.km);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Driver 2 details:\n");
    printf(" Name: %s\n", driver2.name);
    printf(" License number: %s\n", driver2.license);
    printf(" Route: %s\n", driver2.route);
    printf(" Apprrox km driven: %d", driver2.km);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Driver 3 details:\n");
    printf(" Name: %s\n", driver3.name);
    printf(" License number: %s\n", driver3.license);
    printf(" Route: %s\n", driver3.route);
    printf(" Apprrox km driven: %d", driver3.km);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the input and output of a session that shows the problem? Do you enter a whole number of km?

Comment: `"%s"` stops at the first whitespace character, so if the "name" is given as first name and last name, only the first name will be stored in `driver.name` and the last name will be stored in `driver.license`. In other words, you should [edit] the question and show us the input given to the program, and the output received from the program.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", &driver1.name);`

I normally recommend `fgets` over `scanf` with `%s`, but in this case it's more trouble than its worth so I give you this helper function:

```
int fgetstring(FILE *f, char *string, size_t n)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF && c != '\n') {
         if (offset + 1 < n)
             string[offset++] = (char)c;
    }
    string[offset] = 0;
    return (c != EOF);
}
```

This helper function just reads a line into a string. Called like so:

`fgetstring(stdin, driver1.name, 50);`

I expect you may have problems with whitespace left in the buffer after %d. You can eat it a couple of ways, easiest being:

```
#include <limits.h>
int eatwhitespace(FILE *f)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF && isspace(c))
        ;
    if (c != EOF) { ungetc(c, f); return 1; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int offset` better as `size_t offset`.  Rather than call with a magic number 50, consider `fgetstring(stdin, driver1.name, sizeof driver1.name);`.